# Memory error in converting large (14 GB) JSON file to CSV using Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I want to convert a large 14 GB JSON file to CSV using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_json('ferdowsi-data.json')
data.to_csv('data.csv')
```

but I receive a memory error. How do I solve this error and what is the most efficient way of converting large files into CSV?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to share an error-traceback and a snippet of the json-file?

Comment: If you convert the json list to line separated json then you can just process it in chunks by splitting the file.  Obviously 15GB isn't very appropriate for many text based formats